# Using Guzzle to make HTTP requests with GET parameters

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to use Guzzle to make a request from my server, not a requirement. I use cURL and that works, however when I try with Guzzle I get a 403 error saying the client rejected my request which makes me believe the params are not being passed correctly.

This is my cURL code:

```
// Sending Sms
$url = "https://api.xxxxxx.com/v3/messages/send";

$from = "xxxxxx";

$to = $message->getTo();

$client_id = "xxxxxx";

$client_secret = "xxxxxx";

$query_string = "?From=".$from."&To=".$to."&Content=".$content."&ClientId=".$client_id."&ClientSecret=".$client_secret."&RegisteredDelivery=true";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$query_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

This is my Guzzle code now:

```
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', "https://api.xxxxxx.com/v3/messages/send", [
    "From" => "xxxxxx",
    "To" => $message->getTo(),
    "Content" => $content,
    "ClientId" => "xxxxxx",
    "ClientSecret" => "xxxxxx",
    "RegisteredDelivery" => "true"
]);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters):

> You can specify the query string parameters using the `query` request option as an array.
>
> ```
> $client->request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org', [
>     'query' => ['foo' => 'bar']
> ]);
> ```

So just make your array multidimensional, placing your query string parameters in the `query` element of the array.

```
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', "https://api.xxxxxx.com/v3/messages/send", [
    "query" => [
        "From"               => "xxxxxx",
        "To"                 => $message->getTo(),
        "Content"            => $content,
        "ClientId"           => "xxxxxx",
        "ClientSecret"       => "xxxxxx",
        "RegisteredDelivery" => "true",
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you this worked! Think I'm going to be using guzzle now :)

Comment: What if the value of one of the variables contains for example "/", thus making the URL invalid?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler a query string is delimited from the URL by a `?` and regardless, the library will perform URL encoding on variables passed to it.